# General error : 1005 Can't create table ... (errno:150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-migrations

I have to run migrations on my online project but it doesn't work for a foreign key.
I have two tables : media and video_categorie (existing)
Here is my migration file to create the video_categorie file:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateVideoCategorieTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('video_categorie', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nom_fr', 50);
            $table->string('nom_en', 50)->nullable();
            $table->unsignedSmallInteger('ordre')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('video_categorie');
    }
}
```

And the other to create the foreign_key on my media table :

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AddForeignKeyToMediaTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('media', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedInteger('video_categorie_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedSmallInteger('ordre_video')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('video_categorie_id')->references('id')->on('video_categorie');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('media', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign('media_video_categorie_id_foreign');
            $table->dropColumn('video_categorie_id');
            $table->dropColumn('ordre_video');
        });
    }
}
```

When I tried on my local server it works like a charm, my database was updated like I wanted.
But on my web hosting I have this error wheen I try to run

```bash
php artisan migrate
```

```
Migrating: 2022_09_15_092133_create_video_categorie_table
Migrated:  2022_09_15_092133_create_video_categorie_table (7.91ms)
Migrating: 2022_09_15_115815_add_foreign_key_to_media_table

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `stag_db`.`media` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `media` add constraint `media_video_categorie_id_foreign` foreign key (`video_categorie_id`) references `video_categorie` (`id`))

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:712
    708▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    709▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    710▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    711▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 712▕             throw new QueryException(
    713▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    714▕             );
    715▕         }
    716▕     }

      +9 vendor frames
  10  database/migrations/2022_09_15_115815_add_foreign_key_to_media_table.php:20
      Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic("table")

      +22 vendor frames
  33  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

Does anyone know where this is coming from?

I have checked my local and my hosting web version of php and mysql and they are not the same.

Local php : PHP 7.4.3

Hosting php : PHP 7.3.33

Local mysql : mysql  Ver 8.0.30

Hosting mysql : mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.36-MariaDB

Is there a problem with these differences?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Last migrations (php artisan migrate:status):

```bash
| Yes  | 2022_08_18_135729_add_fichier_column_to_contact_table                                                | 32    |
| Yes  | 2022_08_29_120103_add_contact_motif_name_column_to_contact_table                                     | 33    |
| Yes  | 2022_09_15_092133_create_video_categorie_table                                                       | 33    |
| No   | 2022_09_15_115815_add_foreign_key_to_media_table                                                     |       |
| No   | 2022_09_15_120150_add_orph_video_column_to_media_table                                               |       |
+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
```

**EDIT**

After many hours I finally found where the problem was! If it can help other people ;)

On my webhosting the default storage engine that is used is MyISAM, so my new table video_categorie was created with this engine.

But this engine doen't allow to establish relations between tables.

My first migration which create the table video_categorie works but when I try on my second migration to establish a foreign key, it does'nt work due to the video_categorie engine.

I contact my webhosting to change my server mysql configuration to default engine InnoDB.

While waiting for them to answer me I have just run my first migration, then change manually the table engine(ALTER TABLE video_categorie ENGINE = InnoDB).

Finally I run the second migration and it works!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many hours I finally found where the problem was! If it can help other people ;)

On my webhosting the default storage engine that is used is MyISAM, so my new table video_categorie was created with this engine.

But this engine doen't allow to establish relations between tables.

My first migration which create the table video_categorie works but when I try on my second migration to establish a foreign key, it does'nt work due to the video_categorie engine.

I contact my webhosting to change my server mysql configuration to default engine InnoDB.

While waiting for them to answer me I have just run my first migration, then change manually the table engine(ALTER TABLE video_categorie ENGINE = InnoDB).

Finally I run the second migration and it works!!!

Answer (score 0):

The error is informing you that the column type of your primary key on `media` and foreign key on `video_categorie` do not match.

My recommendation would be to change your migrations and make use of the column definition helpers.

**CreateVideoCategorieTable**

```
Schema::create('video_categorie', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id('id');  // using the id column type
    $table->string('nom_fr', 50);
    $table->string('nom_en', 50)->nullable();
    $table->unsignedSmallInteger('ordre')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**AddForeignKeyToMediaTable**

```
Schema::table('media', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreignId('video_categorie_id')->nullable();
    $table->unsignedSmallInteger('ordre_video')->nullable();
    $table->foreign('video_categorie_id')->references('id')->on('video_categorie');
});
```

**Update**

For clarity, the issue is that the column type `integer` and `unsignedInteger` are not compatible and so you need to alter your foreign key column type to be compatible with primary key column type. The above shows how that mapping could be done.

This amendement needs to be done in your **AddForeignKeyToMediaTable** migration, replace the `$table->unsignedInteger('video_categorie_id')->nullable();` statement entirely. If it remains in your migrations anywhere, you'll continue to see the error. You can't add a new `rollback` migration for this statement as it has never executed due to the migrations failing.

Comment: I've made a migrate:rollback to undo the changes and I tried to change the code like you advise but I have the same error : General error 1005...

Comment: @Petitemo Is the error for the same column? Executing the above succeeds when I test it.

Comment: Yes it's on the same column : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `stag_db`.`media` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `media` add constraint `media_video_categorie_id_foreign` foreign key (`video_categorie_id`) references `video_categorie` (`id`)). The fact is that it works on my local server but not on my hosting server.

Comment: @Petitemo Your DB engines are different versions as you've pointed out, however, they are the same as my local installations. Could another migration or anything else be interferring?

Comment: @Petitemo To clarify, you have removed the previous migration from your migration files? If your previous migration attempt is still in a migration file, you'll still get that error and migrations will fail. It needs to be removed entirely.

Comment: I update my question with my migrations status if it could help! I haven't delete the file and re-create a new one I only rollback, modify the code and migrate again. You said that I have to create a new migration instead of what I've done?

Comment: @Petitemo I have updated my answer, hopefully it adds more clarity for you.

Comment: I delete lasts migrations and I re-create them entirely. I still get the same error on the same column. I read that the foreign keys have to be in unsignedBigInteger type but I tried to change it and it still does'nt work at all...

Comment: @Petitemo The `id()` and `foreignId()` column definition types are just syntax sugar (shorthand helpers) for creating the correct key types (unsignedBigInteger). It sounds like you need to go through your migrations as something (not visible from your question) is having an effect.

Comment: Ok I will dig deeper in my migrations but I "only" have 70 migrations... so it will take time ;) Thanks a lot anyway for your help @Peppermintology. If I foound something I will post it.

Comment: @Petitemo Yikes, have fun with that.

Comment: I found that it was due to the default storage engine of mysql! I update my question with the solution. :)

Comment: @Petitemo Pleased to hear you found your solution. Maybe add it as an answer too and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Collation and Character Set: The character set and collation of the columns should match. If they don't match, it can cause issues. Ensure that the collation and character set are the same for both the columns in the foreign key relationship.